# Angular 2- using *ngIf with multiple conditions

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm unable to selectively display links on my nav-bar.
Based on who logs in (user or admin), I want to change which link shows on my nav-bar.

Below is the code for one such instance where the user/admin logs out.

**In navbar.component.html -**

```html
<li *ngIf="authService.userLoggedIn()== true && authService.adminLoggedIn() == false" 
       [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"> 
  <a (click)="onUserLogoutClick()" href="#">Logout</a>
</li>

<li *ngIf="(authService.adminLoggedIn() == true) && (authService.userLoggedIn() == false)" 
      [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
   <a (click)="onAdminLogoutClick()" href="#">Logout</a>
</li>
```

Both `authService.adminLoggedIn()` and `authService.userLoggedIn()` return `tokenNotExpired;`

Below is the relevant code in the **navbar.component.ts -**

```ts
 onUserLogoutClick() {
   this.authService.userLogout();
   this.flashMessage.show('You are now logged out', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000});
   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
   return false;   
 }

 onAdminLogoutClick() {
   this.authService.adminLogout();
   this.flashMessage.show('Administrator now logged out', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000});
   this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
   return false;   
 }
```

The `authService.adminLogout()` and `authService.userLogout()` just clears the token stored in local storage.

I apologize in advance if the mistake that I've made is silly. I'm new to Angular.

Comment: revise your post to be more meaning ful

Comment: how are you identifying if admin logged in or user logged in

Comment: Can you please explain whether authService.adminLoggedIn() and authService.userLoggedIn() return tokenNotExpired but you are testing on boolean true? May I also ask whether you maybe prefer to make the logic as part of the JS code rather than in the template? It does not seem to have a template impact.

Comment: I have different components for admin and user login on the navbar of my landing page.

Comment: @BenDadsetan, I referred to https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt to learn about angular2-jwt

In the section of 
Checking Authentication to Hide/Show Elements and Handle Routing
they also check the condition in *ngIf, I even tried without testing it to boolean value but it still didn't work.
Link - https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#checking-authentication-to-hideshow-elements-and-handle-routing

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can move these multiline conditions and complex conditions to your component method as below

```
showLogout(){
    if(this.authService.userLoggedIn()== true && this.authService.adminLoggedIn() == false)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Also, as the **angular4** has `*ngIf and else` you can use it as

```
 <div *ngIf="showLogout();then userLogout else adminlogout"></div>

<ng-template #userLogout><a (click)="onUserLogoutClick()" href="#">Logout</a></li></ng-template>
<ng-template #adminlogout><a (click)="onAdminLogoutClick()" href="#">Logout</a></li></ng-template>
```

Comment: Why not simplify the `showLogout` *method*? `return this.authService.userLoggedIn() && !this.authService.adminLoggedIn()`.

Comment: @Aravind, Your solution works, but when nobody is logged in, the nav-bar is still showing the logout link for (onAdminLogoutClick). 
The tokens that I generate for admin have the ID of 'admin_token', and the tokens for the user have the ID of 'user_token'. So when I call authService.adminLoggedIn() it returns tokenNotExpired('admin_token') and for authService.userLoggedIn() it returns tokenNotExpired('user_token'). This is how I determine whether the user or the administrator is logged in.

Comment: You need to check if the token is available in your  method

Comment: So is every thing is fine or u need more help

Comment: It's working now. I made some edits. Before checking the method that you suggested (showLogout()), I added another method (clientLoggedIn()) to check if someone (either user or admin) is logged in or not.
The HTML code - 
<div *ngIf="clientLoggedIn()">
        <div *ngIf="showLogout();then userLogout else adminLogout"></div>
        <ng-template.... </ng-template>
        </div>

clientLoggedIn(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('user_token')=== null && localStorage.getItem('admin_token')=== null) 
      return false
    else 
      return true
Thanks, @Aravind.

Comment: I don't, @Aravind! :)

Comment: In angular 7,
<button type="button" (click)="myClick()" *ngIf="shouldShow()">MyButton</button>
The buttons are not showing up even when the method returns true. Not sure whats wrong here. Any clue would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

authService.userLoggedIn() or authService.adminLoggedIn() in your expression wouldn't keep your template informed about who is logged in as your function is invoked only once.

Try make them getter in your service:

```
  get userLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.who.user; // your logic
  }
```

Then in your template:

```
<li *ngIf="authService.userLoggedIn && !authService.adminLoggedIn"...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think should be create a boolean properties in component and using it.
In stead of writing function or complex expression in template.
Function in template reduce performance.
Complex expression make it not readble and maintainable.